# (New to Android) Where to save the destination APK file on device?

Tags: android

Anywhere I currently try to save it I get the message that says "You can't save here, please choose another location"  I realize that I am probably missing something completely obvious, but I thought I would see if anyone here would give a new android developer some insight on how to properly load the application I just made onto my device.  (Already done the keystore stuff)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via `adb` with

```
adb install /path/to/your/apk
```

If adb seems too daunting, you can also click on an apk attached to an email on a device and it will ask if you want to install it.